# scheduling job with Quartz

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I had running the job with Quartz for run automatically each 1 minute with Spring restful web service, but I found the problem.

the log:

```
17:24:00,016 INFO  [stdout] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-6) Hello Letter Printing Timer Quartz! Thu Dec 21 17:24:00 ICT 2017

17:24:00,016 INFO  [stdout] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-6) ini controller testing

17:24:00,016 INFO  [stdout] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-6) ----controller-----

17:24:00,016 ERROR [org.quartz.core.JobRunShell] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-6) Job DEFAULT.6da64b5bd2ee-929cc152-4d2a-4f06-8149-273dd89c6e36 threw an unhandled Exception: : java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.prudential.letter.printing.controller.ModifyFileController.modifyFileForGenerateUniqueID(ModifyFileController.java:20) [classes:]
    at com.prudential.letter.printing.HelloJob.execute(HelloJob.java:20) [classes:]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]

17:24:00,016 ERROR [org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-6) Job (DEFAULT.6da64b5bd2ee-929cc152-4d2a-4f06-8149-273dd89c6e36 threw an exception.: org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception: java.lang.NullPointerException]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.prudential.letter.printing.controller.ModifyFileController.modifyFileForGenerateUniqueID(ModifyFileController.java:20) [classes:]
    at com.prudential.letter.printing.HelloJob.execute(HelloJob.java:20) [classes:]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
    ... 1 more
```

I println in each controller, service implement, and dao implement but from the job just until controller. when from controller to service, I found an error.

my code:

HelloJob.java

```
public class HelloJob implements Job {

    TestingController testing = new TestingController();
    ModifyFileController modify = new ModifyFileController();

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("Hello Letter Printing Timer Quartz! " + new Date());
        testing.getData();
        modify.modifyFileForGenerateUniqueID(); // to controller
    }
}
```

my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class ModifyFileController {

    @Autowired
    private FileService fileService;

    @PostMapping("modify")
    public String modifyFileForGenerateUniqueID() {
        System.out.println("----controller-----");
        return fileService.modify();
    }

}
```

interface:

```
public interface FileService {
    public String modify();
}
```

service impl:

```
@Service
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class FileServiceImpl implements FileService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(FileServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private FileDao fileDao;

    @Autowired
    ConfigProperties configProperties;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public String modify() {
        System.out.println("----service impl-----");
        String data = configProperties.getSeparator();
        String[] result = data.split(";");
        String timeout = configProperties.getTimeout();
        Integer i = Integer.parseInt(timeout);
        return fileDao.modify(result, i);
    }

}
```

Dao:

```
public interface FileDao {
    public String modify(String[] result, Integer timeout);
}
```

Dao Impl:

```
@Repository
public class FileDaoImpl implements FileDao {

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public String modify(String[] delimeter, Integer timeout) {
        // the content here
        return "Success";
    }
}
```

Quartz Listener:

```
@WebListener
public class QuartzListener extends QuartzInitializerListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        super.contextInitialized(sce);
        ServletContext ctx = sce.getServletContext();
        StdSchedulerFactory factory = (StdSchedulerFactory) ctx.getAttribute(QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY);
        try {
            Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
            JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(HelloJob.class).build();
            Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("simple").withSchedule(
                    CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *")).startNow().build();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
            scheduler.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ctx.log("There was an error scheduling the job.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Why the running job don't go to service impl? just stop in controller and then error? Thanks

Comment: See the logs. It has NPE in your controller

Comment: in the log, error show "NullPointerException" .. what it means?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `new` keyword to initialize new Controllers.

Besides, use Spring Dependency Injection.

```
public class HelloJob implements Job {

    @Autowired
    private TestingController testing;

    @Autowired
    private ModifyFileController modify;

    // ...
}
```

The problem is that `ModifyFileController` is also dependent in `FileService` and so on. This object is null when you try to call it that way.

I have to add that from Job, I assume that it is better practise to call methods in `Service` layer and not in `Controller` layer.

Comment: I had already change the code but still error. error show "NullPointerException" in log jboss eap.. any solution?

Comment: How did you change the code? In which exactly line NullPointerException is being thrown?

Answer (score 0):

You should mentally think of a job as being at the same application level as a controller.  You should never call controller methods programatically from other classes like that.  You should interact directly with the FileService in your job.

Comment: I had already change the code but still error. error show "NullPointerException" in log jboss eap.. any solution?